# jQuery Data Attribute not getting values

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, jquery-data

jQuery Data Attribute not working on the most simplest demo possible...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $("#font_selection").change(function(){
    var fontImgName = $(this).data('font-img');
    //var fontImgName = $("#font_selection").data('font-img');

    //var fontImgName = $(this).attr('data-font-img')
    //var fontImgName = $("#font_selection").attr('data-font-img')

    alert(fontImgName);

  });

});
```

I must be missing something, I have tried every combination I can think of with no success, please help!

JSFiddle Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/8fvo3kw0/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8fvo3kw0/3/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $("#font_selection").change(function(){
    var fontImgName = $(this).find('option:selected').data('font-img');      
    alert(fontImgName);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the selected option element:

```
var fontImgName = $(this).find('option:selected').data('font-img');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8fvo3kw0/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the `data` attribute of `select` & your select doesn't have `data` attribute.

I think you want data attribute for selected Item

Use bellow

```
var fontImgName = $(this).find(':selected').data('font-img');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8fvo3kw0/4/)

Answer (score 1):

That is because you're referencing to the `select` element itself.

```
var fontImgName = $(this).find('option:selected').data('font-img');
```

This would find the option that is selected and then access the data attribute of it. What you're doing is, you're selecting the data atribute's value of the select. In your HTML select doesn't have a data- attribute at all.